# ANTLR Runtime version 4.7.2 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.5.1

Tags: mule, antlr, antlr4, mule-esb, mssql-jdbc

I am using Mule EE 3.9.0, Java 8 and MSSQL 8.2.2.jre.

Our application is integration framework developed on mule flows which makes db:insert (internally using mule EE 3.9.0 DB module) for certain flows.

Recently I had to invoke a JAVA component in mule flow to make database calls for which I used MSSQL-JDBC 8.2.2.jre8 version. 
After then I am getting below error running those old db:insert mule flows:

```
ANTLR Tool version 4.7.2 used for code generation does not match the current runtime version 4.5.1ANTLR Runtime version 4.7.2 used for parser compilation does not match the current runtime version 4.5.1ERROR 2020-06-03 11:09:17,946 [DispatchThread: [com.ibm.mq.jmqi.remote.impl.RemoteSession[:/4867ad1f][connectionId=414D5143514D53544D4C303120202020F4F7865E01F7FB26]]] org.mule.exception.CatchMessagingExceptionStrategy:
********************************************************************************
Message               : null (java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError).
Payload Type          : [B
Element               : ........
Element XML           : <db:insert config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database" transactionalAction="NOT_SUPPORTED"> ...
Root Exception stack trace:
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATN; Could not deserialize ATN with UUID 59627784-3be5-417a-b9eb-8131a7286089 (expected aadb8d7e-aeef-4415-ad2b-8204d6cf042e or a legacy UUID).
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNDeserializer.deserialize(ATNDeserializer.java:153)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerLexer.<clinit>(SQLServerLexer.java:424)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerFMTQuery.<init>(SQLServerFMTQuery.java:100)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerParameterMetaData.<init>(SQLServerParameterMetaData.java:347)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.getParameterMetaData(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:3100)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerPreparedStatement.getParameterMetaData(SQLServerPreparedStatement.java:3111)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.getParameterMetaData(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:266)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp2.DelegatingPreparedStatement.getParameterMetaData(DelegatingPreparedStatement.java:266)
at org.mule.module.db.internal.resolver.param.QueryParamTypeResolver.getParameterTypes(QueryParamTypeResolver.java:52)
at org.mule.module.db.internal.resolver.param.DefaultParamTypeResolver.getParamTypesUsingMetadata(DefaultParamTypeResolver.java:74)
at org.mule.module.db.internal.resolver.param.DefaultParamTypeResolver.getParameterTypes(DefaultParamTypeResolver.java:49)
at org.mule.module.db.internal.domain.connection.AbstractDbConnection.getParamTypes(AbstractDbConnection.java:53)
at org.mule.module.db.internal.resolver.query.ParametrizedQueryResolver.getParameterTypes(ParametrizedQueryResolver.java:68)
at org.mule.module.db.internal.resolver.query.ParametrizedQueryResolver.resolve(ParametrizedQueryResolver.java:56)
at org.mule.module.db.internal.processor.AbstractSingleQueryDbMessageProcessor.executeQuery(AbstractSingleQueryDbMessageProcessor.java:48)
at org.mule.module.db.internal.processor.AbstractDbMessageProcessor.process(AbstractDbMessageProcessor.java:81)
at org.mule.execution.ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.execute(ExceptionToMessagingExceptionExecutionInterceptor.java:27)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.execute(MessageProcessorNotificationExecutionInterceptor.java:111)
at org.mule.execution.MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.execute(MessageProcessorExecutionTemplate.java:44)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.executeNext(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:88)
at org.mule.processor.BlockingProcessorExecutor.execute(BlockingProcessorExecutor.java:59)
```

Please could you help why mssql-jdbc is conflicting with mule 3.9.0, and antlr is not able to parse the SQL's in mule anymore.

I have tried to add antlr-runtime and antlr-tool to POM dependencies, but no luck. If I replace mssql-jdbc version 8.2.2.jre with 7.0.0.jre, it starts working fine (which is good thing) but I need some features of mssql-jdbc 8.2.2.jre.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that there is a conflict in the versions used of ANTLR, but it doesn't look like it comes from Mule. Mule 3.9.0 uses ANTLR 3.5.x. The error mentions that the conflict is between ANTLR 4.7.2 and 4.5.1.

Maybe some connectors, drivers or jar libraries are adding those conflicting versions. The JDBC SQL driver is using one of the versions. That can be confirmed but looking at the last lines in the stacktrace:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATN; Could not deserialize ATN with UUID 59627784-3be5-417a-b9eb-8131a7286089 (expected aadb8d7e-aeef-4415-ad2b-8204d6cf042e or a legacy UUID).
at org.antlr.v4.runtime.atn.ATNDeserializer.deserialize(ATNDeserializer.java:153)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerLexer.<clinit>(SQLServerLexer.java:424)
```

The Microsoft class SQLServerLexer is calling the ANTLR 4 class ATNDeserializer.

Maybe a [Maven dependency tree](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-dependency-plugin/examples/resolving-conflicts-using-the-dependency-tree.html) could help to understand where the other version is coming from.

Also using Java verbose classloading (`-verbose:class`) can show where the classes are being loaded from. It can be added as an additional option to wrapper.conf.

By the way, if you are using Mule EE 3.9.0 you should really consider upgrading to Mule EE 3.9.4 that has a big number of fixes.

Comment: You are right, antlr4 v4.5.1 is injected through our another dependency mule-module-sfdc (i.e. SalesForce component). But this module was present since a year back and we had no issues. Nothing changed but my new mssql-jdbc version upgrade to 8.2.2.jre created this error

Comment: Just now, I found that mssql-jdbc.8.X.X.jre tries to perform ATN deserialization through SQLServerLexer if SQL Server major version is less than or equal to 11.    SQLServerFMTQuery f = new SQLServerFMTQuery(sProcString);  ... This ATN deserialize method checks Locale.getDefault() against new Object[] { uuid, SERIALIZED_UUID } and errors. Please could anyone from MSSQL guys help why this is enabled in v8, and how to overcome this??

Comment: Yes you can see the MS SQL JDBC driver calling ANTLR 4 in the stack trace.

Comment: I added that to the response.

Comment: You should be able to exclude one of the dependencies but it could break the other components. Mule 4 doesn't has this problem because it has classloader isolation, so one connector's libraries doesn't conflict with others. You may want to rollback the JDBC driver to a version that doesn't use ANTLR.

Answer (score 0):

mssql-jdbc.8.2.1.jre parse ONLY parametrised SQL queries and make them pre-compiled. While parsing it used ANTLR runtime to validate. In my case the validation was failing because we used mule db:insert as below:

```
<db:insert config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database" transactionalAction="NOT_SUPPORTED">
<db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[insert into EIS.T_TABLE (ID, EXPIRY_TIMESTAMP, INSERT_TIMESTAMP, CC_DATA, CORRELATION_ID) values(#[db_data.ID], #[db_data.EXPIRY_TIMESTAMP.toString()], #[db_data.INSERT_TIMESTAMP.toString()], #[db_data.CC_DATA], #[db_data.MQ_CORRELATION_ID])]]></db:parameterized-query>
```

ANTLR runtime does not like '#',']' and '[' in the parametrised SQL. So, we replaced the mule db:insert as below and it worked fine.

```
<db:insert config-ref="Generic_Database_Configuration" doc:name="Database" transactionalAction="NOT_SUPPORTED">
<db:parameterized-query><![CDATA[insert into EIS.T_TABLE (ID, EXPIRY_TIMESTAMP, INSERT_TIMESTAMP, CC_DATA, CORRELATION_ID) values(:ID, :EXP_TIME, :INSERT_TIME, :CC_DATA, :CORRELATION)]]></db:parameterized-query>
    <db:in-param name="ID" type="NCHAR" value="#[db_data.ID]"/>
    <db:in-param name="EXP_TIME" type="TIMESTAMP" value="#[db_data.EXPIRY_TIMESTAMP.toString()]"/>
    <db:in-param name="INSERT_TIME" type="TIMESTAMP" value="#[db_data.INSERT_TIMESTAMP.toString()]"/>
    <db:in-param name="CC_DATA" type="VARBINARY" value="#[db_data.CC_DATA]"/>
    <db:in-param name="CORRELATION" type="NVARCHAR" value="#[db_data.CORRELATION_ID]"/>
```